# Presenting a view controller modally from an action sheet's delegate in iOS8 - iOS11

Tags: ios, uikit, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

So I noticed that in iOS8 beta 3 (**Update**: still happens in iOS 11.2) on iPad, when attempting to present a view controller from within a delegate method of a `UIActionSheet`, "nothing" happens and a log message is output to the debug console, stating that presentation was attempted while transitioning an alert controller:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x...> on <ViewController: 0x...> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x...>
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**Update:** As of iOS 9 SDK, `UIActionSheet` is deprecated, so do not expect a fix regarding this issue. It is best to start using `UIAlertController` when possible.

---

The problem seems to come from Apple's switch to using `UIAlertController` internally to implement the functionality of alert views and action sheets. The issue is seen mostly on iPad and action sheets, because on iPad, action sheets are presented as a popover within a specified view, and what Apple does is travel the responder chain until it finds a view controller and calls `presentViewController:animated:completion:` with the internal `UIAlertController`. The problem is less obvious on iPhone and with alert views, because there Apple actually creates a separate window, an empty view controller and presents the internal `UIAlertController` on top of that, so it seems to not interfere with other presentation.

I have opened bug report for this issue: **rdar://17742017**. Please duplicate it and let Apple know this is a problem.

As a workaround, I recommend delaying the presentation until the next runloop, using the following method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: Even so it doesn't work for me. Popover fails. iOS8 = trashed everything.

Comment: @Michael What do you mean popover fails?

Comment: It is hard to imagine this bug is still out there. @leo-natan do you have an update from Apple.

Comment: @Pichirichi No, the issue is still open with Apple, and reproduces on 8.1 b1.

Comment: @LeoNatan even if I use dispatch_async, it's the same issue when an existing UIPopoverController tries to open another UIPopoverController. It fails with the same warning message. I have to destroy the existing controller first, and then open the new one.

Comment: This workaround works for `UIActionSheet`'s `showFromRect:` on iPad, iOS 8.1b2.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I actually used this to delay presentation of the popover, but same idea: [self performSelector: @selector(myCallToPresentPopover) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

Comment: @Michael try to replace it with:         `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.51 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
});`

Comment: @Michael I guess this comment is way too late but you could try to do dispatch_after, in my experience dispatch_async not always dispatches outside of the runloop.

Answer (score 31):

You can try to do your job (presenting view controller) in

```
- (void)      actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {}
```

instead of

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {}
```

as @LeoNatan said, *"The problem seems to come from Apple's switch to using UIAlertController internally to implement the functionality of alert views and action sheets"*. So you must to wait the action sheet dismissed, then present the view controller you want.

@LeoNatan's solution just block the UI at main thread, so it'll also make sure the view controller will be presented after the action sheet was dismissed.

Comment: My solution does not block the main thread. Presenting in didDismiss causes the same issue.

Comment: @LeoNatan _"Presenting in didDismiss causes the same issue"_, u mean still cannot fix the issue? Hm.. but I got it fixed perfect, view controller is presented as soon as the action sheet was dismissed :)

Comment: @LeoNatan hm.. the __"block"__ means ur _"delaying the presentation until the next runloop"_ ;)

Comment: In our app, the same "Attempt to present" warning appears. Perhaps it has been fixed in the new iOS 8.1 beta.

Comment: Delaying is the opposite of blocking.

Comment: @HernanArber yeah, I've lots WHYs for iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution and I feel the outcome is more natural too.

Comment: Very simple solution that absolutely works.  Thanks!

Comment: UIActionSheet is dprecated in iOS 8, so this is obviously no longer a valid answer. Thanks Apple! ... for nothing.

Comment: Thanks, save me a lot of time.

Comment: @LeiKan glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately this code doesn't work for me, I think because my problem was not calling presentController method directly  but in the prepareForSegue method so using

```
[segue destinationViewController]
```

I've noticed that if the segue is "push" kind all works correctly, but if it is "modal", just in ipad, i got that error.

Then I've found some new option in storyboard in the segue panel, and i sovled my problem choosing "Current context" for Presentation option

I hope this will be helpful for someone else...
here is the screenshot about the option

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. I created a separate window for alerts and actionsheets in my appdelegate and presented the alerts on it. It worked for me!

```
   self.alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  self.alertWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  UIViewController *dummy = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  [self.alertWindow setRootViewController:dummy];
```

You can present as :

```
[[myAppDelegate appDelegate].alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
  [[myAppDelegate appDelegate].alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: please do not post same issue as a answer. you can ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it in Swift 3 with the following code

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Issuing a

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

on

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

before trying to present another modal view worked for me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please format your answer into a more readable format, and more explanation if possible.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

instead of

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Action view is presented above current VC so thats what causes warning/error. 
when didDismiss is called, action view is already dismissed, so no problems at all :))

Comment: This is the same answer as @Kjuly. The system displayed the same alert on `didDismissWithButtonIndex:` when I asked/answered the question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't see that answer that time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // action sheet presentation
    // or modal view controller presentation
    // or alert view presentation
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 Apple uses UIAlertController internally to implement the functionality of alert views and action sheets. So when you want to show a UIViewController modally after displaying UIActionSheet or UIAlertView in delegate method like

```
(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

and

```
(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

you have to first dismiss UIAlertController as follows:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
{
    UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    }];
}
```

Now you can present a modal UIViewController in iOS 8.