# in iOS8: UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect not work for keyWindow any more

Tags: uipopovercontroller, ios8

As titled, in iOS8, [UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect] does not work for [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow any more.  (It does work in iOS7)

I verified following codes:

```
TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

if (testPopoverController == nil) {
    testPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:test];
    testPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 95*5);


}

CGPoint point = [sender convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toView:nil];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 24, 24);

[testPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Comment: What you want to ask should be how to do it in iOS 8 right?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, any solutions out there?

Comment: Hey...Did u get the answer to this?

Comment: it worked for me at the end..check my answer

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I've come up with is to handle it conditionally. If on iOS 7, use the working code we had for presenting a UIPopoverController on the key window. If on iOS 8, use the following:

```
     viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
     UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = viewController.popoverPresentationController;
     [presentationController setDelegate:self];
     presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = 0;
     presentationController.sourceView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
     presentationController.sourceRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].bounds;

     [viewController setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
     [parentController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This ends up functioning identically to:

```
     self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
     [self.popoverController setDelegate:self];
     [self.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:isLandscape() ? CGSizeMake(480*2, 320*2) : CGSizeMake(320*2, 480*2)];
     [self.padPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGSizeMake(320, 480)
                                      inView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]
                    permittedArrowDirections:0
                                    animated:YES];
```

Comment: i tried out your solution, that dint work for me either .. there are no errors.Im able to display popovers in other views.But in this particular case I'm trying to show the popover no matter where the user is in the application. Thats why I'm using the key window and stuff.But no matter what i do the popover simply doesn't show up in iOS 8

Comment: I'm using it in production code, not sure why it's not working for you, sorry!

Comment: Looks like a combination of the above solution and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854802/presenting-a-view-controller-modally-from-an-action-sheets-delegate-in-ios8-ios has provided me the solution. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change the inView parameter in

```
[testPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

to

```
[testPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:"your current View Controller's view" permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

And make sure it is in dispatch block

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

});

Also kip changing your rect origin n size values if it is within the bounds

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested before your post and I get a downvote for it... :( Smh. I'm just trying to help, no upvote is fine but I think a downvote is harsh for trying to help with a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution found at this link: http://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

1st, let's do this code:

```
if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredContentSize:)]) {
    viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 300.0f);
} else {
    viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200.0f, 300.0f);
}

self.popoverController = [[popoverClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];

if ([self.popoverController respondsToSelector:@selector(setContainerViewProperties:)]) {
    [self.popoverController setContainerViewProperties:[self improvedContainerViewProperties]];
}

self.popoverController.delegate = self;

[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds]
      inView:sender
      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
      animated:YES];
```

I hope this helps. It was tested and works for iOS6-iOS8.

PS. Don't forget to check `viewDidLoad`, and give thanks to the WEPopover Library.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to display it in full view/viewcontroller and not in [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow

So change this code:

```
[testPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

to:

```
[testPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:aViewControllerInYourApp permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Comment: Because you are suggesting to use a viewcontroller, instead of a view 

Comment: Yes, and I don't see anything wrong with that. I think it's more of a design pattern issue than anything??