# AirPrint UIWebView content in iOS8

Tags: uiwebview, ios8, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintformatter

I am trying to AirPrint the contents of my UIWebView (iOS8.1) and am getting an exception with no detail as to what the problem is. If I toggle "Global Breakpoint State" to OFF in Xcode 6.1 then it occasionally prints, although sometimes the page is blank. I am also using an up-to-date installation of Printopia for printing to the iMac.

Is anyone else experiencing problems with AirPrinting in iOS8? Are there any problems with the code below that could be causing this issue?

```
// AirPrint functionality
-(void)printBid {
 if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable]) {      // check that we can print
```

// Use UIPrintInteractionController to print the web view content
   // This generates an exception when Global Breakpoint State is set to On but seems to work when Off

`UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    //pic.delegate = self;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = @"QuickBids";
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;


    UIViewPrintFormatter *formatter = [bidPreviewWebView viewPrintFormatter];
    pic.printFormatter = formatter;


    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed,
      NSError *error) {
        if(!completed && error){
            NSLog(@"Print failed - domain: %@ error code %u", error.domain,
                 error.code);
        }
    };



    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {     // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.


        // iOS 8 Issue on iPad - As a workaround, I recommend delaying the presentation until the next runloop, using the following method:
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854802/presenting-a-view-controller-modally-from-an-action-sheets-delegate-in-ios8
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:shareButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
        });


    }else { // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
        });
    }




}else {    // we can't print so show an alert


    // show simple alert
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Printing Unavailable"
                                          message:@"You cannot print from this device."
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"OK action");
                               }];


    [alertController addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


}`

}

Thanks in advance for any help.