# Update TwitterKit SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-fabric, twitterkit

I have this error :

```
ld: '/Users/MyName/Desktop/ProjectName/PName/PName/Resources/Frameworks/Fabric.framework/Fabric(Fabric.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can I update this or resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Search for bit code on build settings.**Turn it to NO**.This appears because `Fabric.framework` does not  have bitcode in it.
Bitcode will be automatically turned to yes from xcode 7.

***So,either you should get an updated framework from the vendor with bitcode enabled or you should turn bitcode to NO***

[image]

Comment: how I get an updated framework from the vendor with bitcode enabled? It is possible that PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions stop work when it switch bitcode to yes ?

Comment: turning bitcode to NO does not affect  any of the functionalities i guess.It is used for some update purpose in appstore.try turn it to NO,as in the pic,clean the project and run.

Comment: May be twitter will update their framework soon.Have you tried this tip?

Comment: I know when bitcode is no the error gone , but I have problem with PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions and I think that bitcode do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771872/after-update-ios-9-and-facebook-sdk-4-6-the-login-window-not-open