# UIAlertController Error When called in a modal presented view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller which is modally presented and when i run  UIAlertController, keep getting a error message . how can i work around this.

the alert is trigged from a button which checks a text field is empty or not.

```
@IBAction func registerAction(sender: AnyObject) {
if(userEmail.isEmpty){
        alertMessage("Fields Are Empty")
    }
}



func alertMessage(userMessage:String){  
    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Error when i run the alert

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f9bbb9060d0>  on <AlertApp.CustomSignupVC: 0x7f9bb94accb0> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x7f9bbb926660>
```

Comment: its not connected to a segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add it in main operation queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Check this relative question : [Presenting a view controller modally from an action sheet's delegate in iOS8 - iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854802/presenting-a-view-controller-modally-from-an-action-sheets-delegate-in-ios8-ios)

Comment: @MugunthanBalakrishnan Welcome anytime :)