# PresentViewController: animated not displaying on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, modal-dialog, presentviewcontroller

I am integrating `SLService` for `Twitter` into an application. It works great on iPhone but disappears on iPad.

I have integrated on the iPad:

```
  [actionSheet showFromRect:self.myRect inView:self.tableView animated:YES];
```

rather than:

```
 [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

Is there a similar method for the iPad in lieu of `presentViewContoller: Animated:`?

```
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:self.textForTweet];

        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else [self displayAlertBoxWithTitle:@"Tweet Failed" message:@"Please try again later" cancelButton:@"Close"];
}
```

Should I be using a Modal dialog instead?

Comment: isnt action sheet deprecated from ios8 onwards?

Comment: Yes, UIActionSheets are deprecated, but SLComposeViewController is not and that is what appears to be giving the problem.

Comment: Saheb, you may be on the right track. Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24854803/1422252

Comment: I knew something was fishy when i saw action sheet, Presenting SLVC directly will yield ok but presenting it over an action sheet will not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed this error message at first:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <SLComposeViewController: 0x175d6560>  on <ScheduleTableViewController: 0x17538c20> which is already presenting (null)
```

That lead me to discussion of same problem in a different context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854803/1422252).

Resolved the issue by suggested work around:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
```